# Tags and tag synonyms for Drupal/Backdrop

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

Given the tight similarities between Drupal 7 and Backdrop, some tags that are currently prefixed with `drupal-` may now be applicable to both CMSs. I'm thinking in particular of a [question/answer I added recently](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21085/how-do-i-get-views-working-with-civicrm-and-backdrop) related to Views.

There is a tag called [drupal-views](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-views) that has a synonym of `views`. So if I try to use `views` it gets remapped to `drupal-views` -- would it be better to reverse this to go in the other direction? That way `backdrop-views` and `drupal-views` could both end up at `views`, since there is a strong likelihood that discussions around one CMS related to views will also relate to the other?

Answer (score 4):

I don't feel strongly either way, but would note that Backdrop and Drupal are likely to become increasingly dissimilar over time.